# RecyclerView don't show inserted SQLite data instantly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

When the user from a `FragmentDialog` type his data into the edittexts and press the save button, the data should instantly show in the `recyclerView`, but that dosn't happend. To get/show the latest data, you have to *restart the app*

I have used a temporary solution where I pass data from the `FragmentDialog` to the `mainActivity` via a interface and then I directly pass that data into the arraylist for the recyclerView. This work, but dosn't look like a propor solution. I wish a "correct" way to do it

I have also tried to set adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); different places without any succses

**DialogFragment class where the user type his data and is then insertet to SQLite database**

```
public class DialogAdd extends DialogFragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_productdialog,container, false);



    name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_productname);
    quantity = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_qantity);
    location = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_location);
    normalPrice = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_normalPrice);
    offerPrice = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_offerPrice);

    okButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_okButton);
    okButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#2fbd4b"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (name.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You must add a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {


                DialogAddListener addListener = (DialogAddListener) getActivity();

                dbHelper.insertData(name.getText().toString(), quantity.getText().toString(), location.getText().toString(), normalPrice.getText().toString(), offerPrice.getText().toString());
                addListener.getDialogData(name.getText().toString(), quantity.getText().toString(), location.getText().toString(), normalPrice.getText().toString(), offerPrice.getText().toString());


                getDialog().dismiss();
            }


        }
    });

    return rootView;

}
```

**The mainActivity class that instantiate the recyclerview,sqlite and adapters**.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogAdd.DialogAddListener{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shoppinglist_mainactivity);



    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    addbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogAdd = new DialogAdd();
            dialogAdd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "addDialog");
        }
    });



    //RecyclerView
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_shoppinglist);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(App.getAppContex());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);



    initializeData();
    adapter = new ShoplistAdapter(shopListItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}



private void initializeData(){

    shopListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    resultset = databaseHelper.getAllData();

    if (resultset.moveToFirst()){
        while(!resultset.isAfterLast()){
            shopListItems.add(new ShopListItem(resultset.getString(1), resultset.getString(2), resultset.getString(3), resultset.getString(4), resultset.getString(5)));
            resultset.moveToNext();

            totalPrice.setText("Total cost: $" + "26");
            totalItems.setText("Total items: " + resultset.getCount());
        }
    }
    resultset.close();
}


//This is only used to show the data instantly
@Override
public void getDialogData(String name, String qty, String location, String price1, String price2) {
    shopListItems.add(new ShopListItem(name, qty, location, price1, price2));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) which automatically listens for changes in `Uri`. And notify changes via `contentResolver.notifyChanged(uriOfInsertedData)`. The beast way is to use a `ContentProvider` to make all thins thing work appropriately.

Or for an easier way, register an Observer in a singleton for your database and notify it upon changing. In general this will do the same and you will not have any relations between components. It takes some code to post so I hope you will figure it out.

**Update 2016-03-09**, based on your comment

If you implemented example 1, it doesn't tell you how to monitor for changes. There is no existing mechanism for this case.

The best approach to implement this mechanism is to use an Observer pattern.

I would go with a singleton that hosts Observers.

You can extend [Observable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html) (which already has logic for storing a list of Observers, notifying and removing them) and make a singleton of it.

Register Observer by calling `addObserver()` wherever you need to listen to (don't forget to call `deleteObserver()` to avoid Activity leaks).

Now, whenever you call `insert` or modify a database in any way, make sure to call `notifyObservers("tablename")` of `Observable` singleton.

This way all observers will get notified the table was modified (passing a table name is an example, you can use any Object there to inform your components about the change)

Then in `update()` of your `Observer`, check if the table you wish to monitor is updated, if so, reload the data as you normally would do.

Comment: I just implemented approach 1# from this example: 
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

But it dosn't say anything about Observer. Shall I registerer an Observer inside the singleton method?